# Reduce the Appbar Button Size in Bottom appbar In windows Universal app For the Mobile View

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am working on the project of  windows universal platform(UWP).In this Project I have a issued regarding to the bottom Appbar.

I designed a bottom Appbar and add a 7 Appbar Button.which is displayed Properly in desktop and tabulate view, but in mobile view its not properly displayed. I captured a bottom Appbar photo of the both Mobile and Desktop view.
so kindly give a solution for mobile view how i manage all 7 appbar button?
how to reduce appbar button size ? so it will display proper in mobile view.

**Code:**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="applicationbar" Background="#FFE45427">
        <StackPanel x:Name="bottombar"   Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <AppBarButton Label="HOME" x:Name="appbarhome" Click="appbarhome_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/product-default-small.png" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>



            <AppBarButton Label="Sales" x:Name="appbarsales" Click="appbarsales_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_sales.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="Product" x:Name="appbarproduct" Click="appbarproduct_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_product.png" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton Label="POS" x:Name="appbarpos" Click="appbarpos_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_pos.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton Label="Customer" x:Name="customer" Click="customer_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_customers.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton Label="About US" x:Name="aboutUs" Click="aboutUs_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_aboutus.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Label="Logout" x:Name="mobile_logout_commandbar" Click="mobile_logout_commandbar_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/DashboardImages/menu_logout.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>

            </AppBarButton>


        </StackPanel>

    </AppBar>


</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

**Image:**

[image: Image of the Bottombar for Mobile and Dekstop view]

Comment: You should react to view size changes, when its narrow, put some of the items in the [SecondaryCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279434) menu. Reducing width of buttons make them harder to tap and is not a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can provide Minheight and MaxHeight to reduce button size but it will not look better in Mobile view so we need to use Menuflylaouts.

Code:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="OpenWith" Label="More.."  x:Name="more_item">
                    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-31,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE45427" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="70"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Logout" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"   Click="logout_Click" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="About Us" FontSize="13" Padding="8,8,0,8"  Click="aboutus_click" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                </AppBarButton>
```

and this way we can easily add muliple button in app bar and it will look better in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend change in design. If thats not an option go for horizontal scrollviewer that contains all your appbar buttons.